# Switching from a Singleton to Dependency Injection, and calling a static method that requires a DB connection

Tags: php, oop

I currently have a database wrapper that uses a Singleton, like so:

```
class Database {
    private static $db;

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!self::$db) {
            self::$db = new PDO();
        }
        return self::$db;
    }
}
```

I also have a User class that has a few methods I want to call statically, but they require a database connection, which I'm doing like so:

```
class User {
    private static $db;

    public function __construct() {
        self::$db = Database::getInstance();
    }

    public static function someMethod() {
        self::$db->someQuery();
    }
}

User::someMethod();
```

My question is, how would I accomplish the same thing using Dependency Injection instead of Singleton, without making multiple DB connections?

Comment: What Dependency Injection library are you using? In Zend Framework for example by default you get the same instance. Else you have to write `$di->newInstance('My\B');`. Look [here](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.di.quick-start.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would simply pass the DB connection to the constructor like this:

```
class User {
    private $db;

    public function __construct($db) {
        if ($db instanceof Database) {
            $this->db = $db;
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Give me a Database object');
        }
    }

    public function someMethod() {
        $this->$db->someQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: But this not makes sure you are using the same instance in whole application. So you need one additional layer. (DI-Container)

Comment: @redreggae Good comment.  A DI-container is useful for complex applications to manage the proper instantiation of objects to be utilized for dependency injection.

Comment: @mistermartin I am trying to understand your use case here. Typically one would want to do dependency injection either through a constructor (which indicates an object is actually being instantiated) or via some sort of setter function (which again would suggest a stateful object has been instantiated).

Comment: @MikeBrant You don't understand why I would want to call a method statically that requires a database connection? I'm fairly new to OOP so I'm open to new suggestions. Let's say I want to check whether or not a username exists. It makes more sense (I think) to call the method statically: `if(User::exists($username)) {}` than it does to first instantiate it: `$user = new User(); if($user->exists($username)) {}` I'm not sure how this would be accomplished by your example. Perhaps, instead of throwing an exception I should still use a getInstance() method, even though it's not a singleton?

Comment: @mistermartin I guess my confusion is that in your original code example, `User::someMethod()` would not work, in that the constructor for User would never be called so you would not have a database object to work with. In dependency injection, you are introducing some state (i.e. some object or other dependency) into the class (either via a constructor or setter).  This basically excludes static methods that rely on such state from being functional.

Comment: @MikeBrant but in my original code example, the code does work. Have you tried it? The method, although not being called as part of an instantiated object, still has access to its own properties and methods.

Comment: @mistermartin That is odd, as I would not have thought that the constructor would be called for a static method call.  One other dependency injection option for static calls would be to do `User::exists($username, $db)` passing the DB object specifically to the static method.